# Hibernate jpa entity manager not being closed in spring service layer

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-transactions, lazy-initialization

I am developing a web service application using Spring Boot and Hibernate JPA. I have a layered architecture which consists of request controller layer, business logic (service) layer, and data access (repository) layer. The domain model/entity are:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private List<Address> addresses;
}

@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

As you can see, I have a User entity with one to many unidirectional relationship with address with lazy loading strategy. In repository layer, I have a simple user repository which extends spring data JpaRepository.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

In service layer, simple user fetching method without business logic.

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public User getUser(Long id) {
        return this.userRepository.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

In controller simple user resource controller method.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/users")
public class UserResource {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUser(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        return this.userService.getUser(userId);
    }
}
```

My problem is when I try to get user from service layer, I will also get addresses of user though it is declared for lazy initialization. I also haven't enable transaction. I haven't called any getter method anywhere except when JSON serialization in controller. Hibernate JPA entity manager will still be open in controller layer. But I can't figure how. Wasn't I supposed to get lazy initialization exception?

Comment: Do you really have mapping annotation on fields and not getters? From what I know, Hibernate allows you to get ID of lazy association without fetching the object if the field access is property (getters). Take a look at [this](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-TipsAndTricks#jive_content_id_How_can_I_retrieve_the_identifier_of_an_associated_object_without_fetching_the_association) for details.

Comment: I do have getters and setter. I removed it only to show relationship between entities and keep the post short. Thanks

Comment: And do you also have the @Id annotation in Address class on getter instead of field? Because that would explain the behavior you're seeing

Comment: I didn't had @Id annotation in Address class on getter. But I set it right away and checked, still same issue. Thanks

Comment: There is probably some magic under the hood which I don't fully understand. I will try to look into how this works internally and post it as an answer if I figure it out. For now just remember that getting ID of lazy association does not necessarily trigger fetching of that association under certain conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time. Just for the information, I am using latest release of spring boot (1.2.6.RELEASE) with it's managed other framework version. I also tried to dig in this spring application architecture, but all the post with similar architecture said that entity manager was supposed to be closed in repository layer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Boot registers an OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor (check the class JpaBaseConfiguration), which ensures that the entity manager is open for the complete request, which means, the lazy collection can be resolved while serializing the entity to JSON.

If you want to disable that behaviour, add the configuration `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` to your application.properties.

Comment: Totally worked... Thank dunni and bohuslav for the help... I always think official documentations being perfect reference material, but haven't able to apply those discipline in practice. Thanks brothers